# Binary Coded Decimal dtype in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm multiplying a large 2-D matrix (`dtype=np.bool`) by a 1-D vector (`dtype=np.uint32`) in numpy using `matmult` (i.e. dot product).

```
np.matmul(matrix, vector, out=vector)
```

It works fine, but I keep running out of memory on the larger calcs I'm doing.

One thing that has struck me is the result vector from the dot product - By chance - I only care about *units* returned - so for example, in a returned result vector - say, an element containing integer 1234, only the 4 matters, for 36 only the 6 matters, and so on...

It's a bit of a long shot, but much in the same way as binary integers will seamlessly roll over when they overflow - for example int8 will increment as follows: 254, 255, 256, 0, 1, 2....

I was wondering if there was a way of creating a dtype that would store only a nibble (or a byte if nibbles aren't supported) such that **only the decimal units are carried in any arithmetic operation**?

This is almost certainly impossible with regular binary encoding because the decimal units are stored across all powers of 2.  But, if there was a BCD encoded dtype for numpy (or a way of efficiently constructing one) then I could perhaps only store the LSB of any arithmetic operation and still track the units perfectly, silently discarding the other bytes on each arithmetic operation; similar to the example given for overflowing with numpy's int types.

I know I can convert backwards and forwards from BCD to Binary - but that's missing the point - the whole calculation must be done in BCD for this to work.  Any conversion will just require more memory.

Whatever `dtype` is created to store the result by `matmult` at the moment, must be large enough to store length(vector)*max(vector)*max(matrix[row]) - this is typically an unsigned 32-bit number (specifically for my problem it's 522659*9*1)... too large for `uint16`; but immediately after this I'm discarding most of the result with (result_vector % 10), which would be storable in an 8-bit unsigned dtype.

The memory waste is considerable (profiling show the use of `uint32` for the result means that in my case ~1TB of memory is required where the result could be stored in ~254gb if it was restricted to `uint8`).

So is there any way of discarding the result of a calculation by restricting the types you feed into it - either using BCD, or otherwise?  Tests show that if I make the input vector `int8` the calculation proceeds without complaint but rolls over as described above - so it *could* work with the right type.

However, my guess is I'd have to completely implement a bcd type and all it's operations from scratch to do this?  Or implement my own custom matrix calculation?

I'm happy to do either, but wanted to check I'm not missing a trick first!

One last thing - profiling shows that scipy.spare matrices cannot sufficiently exploit the zeros in my matrix, so there is no memory saving to be had using this trick.  The cost of indexing outweighs the saving and more memory is used than with regular numpy.

I've looked at using structured dtypes and views, which seem to be ballpark what I'm looking for, but I don't think either fits the requirements here.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try taking everything mod 10 before the multiplication. Also try doing the dot product row by row to take up only O(|row|) memory at a time.

Comment: The mod 10 must happen after the multiplication of the matrix and the vector.  Although I could do it row-by-row (i.e. on each result element as it is created).

Comment: What is the approx. shape of matrix and how large is the percentage of nonzero entries? Normally the binary matrix should take by far most of the memory (1 Byte per entry, vs. 4 Byte per entry for uint32). But it is also not too difficult to compress the matrix in memory...

Comment: The matrix is triangular - with top right being 1s, and bottom left being 0s.

Comment: So the whole upper triangular is completely filled with ones and the lower part has only zeros? This would simplify this problem a lot.

Comment: Very much so - but there doesn't seem to be a way to take advantage of this using off-the-shelf numpy/scipy functions, I'd need to write a custom multiplier to do this  which is fine, but wanted to check there wasn't a trick I'm missing - for example scipy sparse matrix can optimise for the 0s, but not the 1s - as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bit of a memory reduction with `uint8` type, and some modulo division:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.choice([True,False],size=(10000,10000))
vector = np.random.randint(0,10000,10000).astype('uint32')

def func1(matrix,vector):
    z = np.empty(1,dtype='uint8')
    v = np.empty(vector.shape[0],dtype='uint8')
    for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
        z = np.tensordot(row,vector,axes=(-1,-1))
        v[i] = z%10
    return v

def func2(matrix,vector):
    z = np.empty(1,dtype='uint8')
    v = np.empty(vector.shape[0],dtype='uint8')
    for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
        np.matmul(row,vector,out=z)
        v[i] = z%10
    return v
```

`matmul` works quicker in this instance. Timing wise:

```
%timeit func1(matrix,vector)
668 ms ± 3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit func2(matrix,vector)
418 ms ± 1.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It would be feasible to try to compute each sum to iteratively work on an object which is of `uint8` type, however most cases I don't see this being worth it -- the intermediary objects here may be large integers, but only *one* is produced at a time for the `func2` function. So even if the matmul for a row and the vector is a large number, there is only ever one that is stored in memory at a time.

`numpy` may in fact write iteratively to `z` here anyway, in which case the issue is moot -- it may be worth looking at the source code to double check this, if it is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiplication with a triangular boolean matrix**

In this case the huge boolean matrix (273 GB for 522659,522659) isn't needed at all. Instead of 273GB RAM for a simple algorithm without using in memory compression or other tricks, 2MB RAM is enough.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def mult_tri(vector):
    out=np.empty(vector.shape[0],dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in nb.prange(vector.shape[0]):
        #accumulator is uint64 to prevent overflow
        acc=np.uint64(0)
        for j in range(i,vector.shape[0]):
            acc+=vector[j]
        out[i]=acc%10
    return out
```

**Timings**

```
vector = np.random.randint(0,9,522659).astype(np.uint8)
%timeit res_1=mult_tri(vector)
#17.4 s ± 234 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```